# file-list with env variable

Tags: shell, csh

In linux, I have a file-list named ***file_list.txt***, where the paths in that list include also an env variable (for this example, the file listed in that file-list is ***$HOME/myfile***).

```
> cat file_list.txt
$HOME/myfile

> ls `cat file_list.txt`
ls: $HOME/myfile: No such file or directory

> ls $HOME/myfile
/home/user/myfile
```

Why is that? How can I run operations (such as ls, less, vim etc) on the files listed in the file-list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expand the variables you will need something like:

```
$ sh -c "ls `cat file_list.txt`"
```

In this case, the commands are read from string and therefore extending variables if any.

```
$ eval "ls `cat file_list.txt`"
```

Just in case check also this question: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/1135424)

Comment: Thank you for your response. When trying it, however, I get the following error (same response to either of the options you gave):
`Illegal variable name`